# Android Java cast long to enum problem

Tags: java, android, types, casting

I have an issue with Java cast long type to Enum's type.
I'm using this code :

```
public enum RPCPacketDataType {
    PT_JSON(1),
    PT_BINARY(2);

    private int value;
    RPCPacketDataType(int i){
        this.value=i;
    }
    public int getNumericType(){
        return value;
    }
}

static RPCPacketDataType tmpPacket_packetType;
```

And I need to do something like this :

```
case 2:
{
    long intVal = Long.parseLong(thisPart);                             
    if(intVal == 0){
        isBad = true; break;
    }
  tmpPacket_packetType=intVal;
  break;
}
```

where thisPart is just a string : `String thisPart;`
And the error says : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to RPCCommucatorDefines.RPCPacketDataType`

Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: You can't cast a primitive to an enumerated type in Java.  Members of an enumeration are Objects, and not related to any of the types that support auto-boxing from primitive types.  In short, you need to write a method that does the conversion for you.

Comment: That's something that I'm not sure how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a method, probably in RPCPacketDataType:

```
public static RPCPacketDataType valueOf(int value) {
    ...
}
```

Then call that from your case statement. Given that the value can only be an integer, you should almost certainly be using `Integer.parseInt` instead of `Long.parseLong`.

How you implement the `valueOf` method is up to you - you *could* iterate through the `EnumSet` of all values trying to find a match, or create a `HashMap` from Integer to `RPCPacketDataType`, or potentially just an array (with validation). It will depend on what's in your enum, and how many values there are to look through.

Note that you should also consider what to do if `valueOf` is passed a value which doesn't correspond to any enum value - one option is to return `null` (and probably test for that explicitly in the calling code); another is to throw an exception.

Comment: Actually for the example in my question,which is the best way to do this?

Comment: @Bombastic: With only a couple of values, I'd probably just use a switch statement. But what you should do if you're given a different value will depend on where you're getting the value from etc.

Comment: So basically I did something like this : switch(value){  case PT_JSON: {****}    } I get the idea with the switch,but not really sure what to do to get the things work for me...